# wrong Error Name 'file' can be undefined in python pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXnb8.png)
Why it's showing an Error

try:
file = open("main.py")
age = int(input("Enter age: "))
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
print("Enter valid Number")
else:
print("How are you?")
finally:
file.close()

Answer (score 2):

Instead of **open**, try **with open**, and remove the finally statement with the close.
This will automatically close it.